# How do I get my VPN to work even when my firewall is active?

Tags: vpn, firewall

I have subscribed to a VPN service, but it seems that it does not work whenever my firewall is active.

I have up until now used Firestarter to configure my firewall, but it has no options for allowing a VPN connection. Nor does gufw.

What do I do to keep my firewall active, and still be able to connect to my VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that works with Firestarter.

I use OpenVPN, so I opened `/etc/firestarter/user-pre` and added the following lines:

```
# Allow traffic on the OpenVPN inteface
$IPT -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

Then I restarted the firewall. Stopping it and starting it within the Firestarter interface seemed to suffice.

The solution was [here](http://www.fs-security.com/docs/vpn.php).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link; http://www.howtoadvice.com/FirestarterVPN
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It does look promising, but the instructions in that link are very heavily tied to using VPNC, which I am not using. A more general solution would be good.